Is there a way to find the unitary diagonalization of a sparse normal matrix in SciPy?
A normal matrix A can be diagonalized as A = U D UH where U is unitary and D is diagonal. Is there a way to actually find this diagonalization in SciPy?
I've tried using eigsh/eigs, but that doesn't find all the eigenvalues/eigenvectors, and the eigenvectors it does find aren't guaranteed to be orthogonal if there are eigenspaces of dimension greater than 1.
There is scipy.linalg.schur, which does what I need on a dense matrix, but it doesn't seem to have a scipy.sparse.linalg equivalent. The matrices I'm working with are too large to be stored in dense format, so I'm stuck working with scipy.sparse.

Are you looking for Singular Value Decomposition? If so you can try scipy.linalg.svd.

If you don't find it in sparse.linalg you won't find it else where (in scipy).

It's a bit unusual to require a full spectrum of a sparse matrix.

@VardanGrigoryants A priori, SVD will give A = U D V*, but will not guarantee that V and U are the same matrix, so it would not solve op's problem

Do you need to output the U matrix (the base-change?)
If so, is there any guarantee that you can find a sparse U? Because otherwise you are going to end up with the same storage problem…
Also how does schur solve your problem? Is there a guarantee that the triangular matrix is the decomposition is going to be diagonal in the normal case?

@tbrugere yes, the triangular matrix given by Schur is diagonal if the matrix is normal. But you're right, the diagonalizing matrix might not be sparse, which does make things a bit more complicated. Maybe the problem isn't actually feasible to solve in Python (at least, not running it on my laptop).
